# Trying to do a loop on worksheets while pasting a value from an array on the same row/column of each sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to loop through worksheets, then paste for example value 1 from an array on sheet 1 in `A2`, value 2 from array on sheet 2 in `A2` and so on.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this in `VBA`?

Comment: I'd look at the `worksheets` collection, then an incremented counter to go through the array, like so `array(myCounter)`  a `for next` loop from 1 to the count of sheets?  Have a go and post code that doesn't work if needed.

Comment: Not really familiar with vba. Pretty brand new. Mind posting a sample code. Hardest part for me is having the value paste from the array? I was able to figure out the sheet loop